# How do I repeat music using pygame.mixer?

Tags: python, pygame

I have created the following code that plays mp3 music using pygame.mixer. However, the music does not repeat. Any idea's on how I would make it so that the music does repeat? Here is the code:

```
playlist = list()
playlist.append ( "put music here.mp3" )
playlist.append ( "put music here.mp3" )

pygame.mixer.music.load ( playlist.pop() )  
pygame.mixer.music.queue ( playlist.pop() )
pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent ( pygame.USEREVENT )  
pygame.mixer.music.play()           

a = 0

running = True
while a == 0:
   while running:
      for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT:    
            if len ( playlist ) >1:       
               pygame.mixer.music.queue ( playlist.pop() )`
```

Comment: Probably because you pop the songs off your playlist and never put them back on

Answer (score 7):

According to the [pygame documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.play) you can pass in `-1` for `pygame.mixer.music.play()` to repeat the music indefinitely.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean can you write out that line of code for me please sorry I'm new to the python community

Comment: @user5817193 didn't you read documentation ? `pygame.mixer.music.play(loops = -1) `

Answer (score 7):

```
pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=-1)
```

gave me error:

```
pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=-1)
TypeError: play() takes no keyword arguments
```

What did work is passing just the number:

```
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
```

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

To play a music `X` times use, `pygame.mixer.music.play(X)`, i.e.:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode(pygame.display.list_modes()[-1]) # smallest resolution available
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("test.wav")
pygame.mixer.music.play(5) # repeat 5 times
pygame.mixer.music.queue("test2.wav")   # queue test2.wav after test.wav plays 5 times
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
clock.tick(10)
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
    pygame.event.poll()
    clock.tick(10)
```

---

**PS:**

- I was able to play music with `pygame` **only** after creating a `display`.