# run a certain code while it detects something python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, driver

This code is used to play an alarm if it detects the driver is drowsy

```
if args["alarm"] != "":
    t = Thread(target=sound_alarm,
        args=(args["alarm"],))
    t.daemon = False
    t.start()
```

The whole code looks like this:

```
if ear < EYE_AR_THRESH:
        COUNTER += 1

        # if the eyes were closed for a sufficient number of
        # then sound the alarm
        if COUNTER >= EYE_AR_CONSEC_FRAMES:

            # if the alarm is not on, turn it on
            if not ALARM_ON:
                ALARM_ON = True

                # check to see if an alarm file was supplied,
                # and if so, start a thread to have the alarm
                # sound played in the background
                if args["alarm"] != "":
                    t = Thread(target=sound_alarm,
                        args=(args["alarm"],))
                    t.daemon = False
                    t.start()

            # draw an alarm on the frame
            cv2.putText(frame, "DROWSINESS ALERT!", (10, 30),
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)
            fan_on()




# otherwise, the eye aspect ratio is not below the blink
# threshold, so reset the counter and alarm
else:
    COUNTER = 0
    ALARM_ON = False
    fan_off()
```

To keep it simple. An alarm will sound if it detects the driver is drowsy.
How can I run the alarm while it detects the driver is drowsy, because at the meantime the alarm only run once.

This is my sound alarm method:

```
def sound_alarm(path):
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load(path)
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you doing this in a loop? if so we can't see it. If not, than you'll get in this code only once and exit...

Comment: How can I not get the code run only once? I want to run this thread while it detects being drowsy

Comment: You need to wrap your code in a `while` loop.
For example, modify the code inside the thread to `print 'hello'`. you'll see it running only once  

But if you will have the following:
`while True: print 'hello'` (can't have newline in a comment)
You'll see it printed multiple times.

You need to do the same in your code

Comment: I tried not to use a thread. Now, The alarm sounds while it is being detected but the sound is not be able to finish

Comment: Post the full `sound_alarm()` function code

Comment: edited sir,,...

Comment: when I wrap the thread of alarm on While True the code shows an error double free or corruption

Comment: It is unclear where the `if ear < EYE_AR_THRESH... else` block is executed. who calls this?

Comment: the if ear < EYE_AR_TRESH is inside a foreloop

Comment: the structure is like this 
while True
    for 
       if<EYE_AR_TRESH

Comment: It's really hard to understand your example, Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and provide a better code example, that shows better what's happening

Comment: lol do I need to post the whole code because it is long

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I repeat music using pygame.mixer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35068209/how-do-i-repeat-music-using-pygame-mixer)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use a `while` loop, in order to **repeat** your code until a certain condition becomes ***False***

The main structure of the `while` loop looks like:

```
while condition_which_is_true:
    do_something()
```

So, in this particular situation, I would do the following:

```
if ear < EYE_AR_THRESH:
    COUNTER += 1

    # if the eyes were closed for a sufficient number of
    # then sound the alarm
    if COUNTER >= EYE_AR_CONSEC_FRAMES:

        # if the alarm is not on, turn it on
        while not ALARM_ON:
            ALARM_ON = True

            # check to see if an alarm file was supplied,
            # and if so, start a thread to have the alarm
            # sound played in the background
            if args["alarm"] != "":
                t = Thread(target=sound_alarm,
                    args=(args["alarm"],))
                t.daemon = False
                t.start()

        # draw an alarm on the frame
        cv2.putText(frame, "DROWSINESS ALERT!", (10, 30),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)
        fan_on()

# otherwise, the eye aspect ratio is not below the blink
# threshold, so reset the counter and alarm
else:
    COUNTER = 0
    ALARM_ON = False
    fan_off()
```

Please, note that, as you haven't provided a fully working code example it's very difficult to help you

Comment: the problem is when i wrap the sound_alarm method on while true im getting an error saying error double free or corruption